# bootstrap responsive cutting footer background

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I got a problem. I'm using Twitter Bootstrap as a framework for my website http://www.bouq.de . Now I have the responsive feature enabled. When I view the site on an smartphone with 320px width or scale the browser window to a small size the background of the footer ist being cut with a margin about 20px. But I want to have the footer background be show on the full width.

Like when u do the same procedure with http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/ it dosent put margins to the footer background.

And I'm not quite sure how to make this now :)

Here is my footer code

```
<footer>
<section class="footer-top">
    <div class="container" >
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span4">
                <div class="bouq-footer-desc-wrapper">
                    <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' );?>/img/bouq-logo-footer.png" />
                    <p class="bouq-footer-desc">bouq. ist eine kreative Künstlerplattform mit familiärem Charakter, fokussiert auf die Produktion und Vermarktung von anspruchsvoller, elektronischer Musik und der damit verbundenen Kultur.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span4">
                <?php if ( function_exists('dynamic_sidebar')) dynamic_sidebar("footer-left"); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="span4">
                <?php if ( function_exists('dynamic_sidebar')) dynamic_sidebar("footer-right"); ?>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="footer-bottom">
    <div class="container" >
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="law">
                    <a href="/impressum">Impressum</a> | <a href="mailto:info@bouq.de">Kontakt</a> | &copy; bouq. c/o Level Eins <?php the_time('Y') ?> | designed by <a href="http://www.upplex.de" target="_blank" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Webdesign by upplex.de" >upplex</a>  <p class="pull-right"><a href="#">Nach oben</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

On line 964 in your responsive CSS, upplex-framework-responsive.min.css, you have the following declaration:

```
  @media (max-width:767px) { body { 
  padding-left: 20px; 
  padding-right: 20px; 
  }}
```

This is giving anything from 767px a margin on either side of the body.  You need to remove/override this.

Comment: Ok tryed that, it works but not as it supposed to work. When I do that the navbar above is hidden 20px left and right. And it would be nice if the content still stays with this setting

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed it :)

```
 footer,   .page-title-container {
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: -20px;   }

.page-title-container-wrapper,   .bouq-footer-ext {     padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;   }
```

Just had to add paddings in 2nd wrapper